# what are the best settings to put my nikon p520 on for everyday outdoor shots?

Tags: nikon

My photos are coming out way overexposed, could someone please tell me the best settings for everyday outdoor shots in bright light

Comment: What settings are you using? What have you tried? How much do you want to learn (vs just getting automatic results)? Can you post some examples?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the photos on a computer? Sometimes I find it hard to judge exposure off the LCD screen while in that same bright environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re shooting on manual without understanding metering and exposure, you’re going to have a rough time.

There are no universal settings - it’s all about conforming to the light you have available and playing within the iso/aperture/shutter speed sandbox pending the look you’re trying to get.

If you want to just pick up your camera and go and really just don’t want to use the full auto modes for some reason, then go with ‘P’ mode or Av mode using 400ISO. Change the aperture as you see fit. Realize that you may run into trouble if you don’t pay attention to your shutter speeds to make sure they are within your handholdable range.

Comment: To be quite sure you are in a handholdable range you could also set the ISO in auto mode and set a maximum ISO (for example 6400). But the shutterspeed is also depending on what you are trying too shoot because a moving target will need a different shutter speed than a tree if you don't want it blurry for example.

Comment: Good points! @LuZel